# json jquery post request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {

            var content = $('#content').html();

            var data = {"content":content};


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {content:content},
                success function (data) {
                    alert('Hello!');
                }

            });


        });

    });        
</script>

<div id="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
```

ajax.php

```
echo json_encode($_POST['content']); ?>
```

Nothing happens... WhatI really want to achieve is to get that alert box and get the return data, but I am lost since I don't get any errors or nothing.

Comment: If you navigate directly to `/ajax.php`, do you get any results?

Comment: Undefined, since i guess its the ajax who does the call :P

Comment: Add an error handler under the .ajax
error function (data) {alert(data);}

Comment: What is undefined?  Can you reach your `ajax.php` file?  Place a simple echo command there to see that you get results..

Comment: I can reach my ajax.php file, yes.

Comment: Are you getting the 'Hello' alert then?

Comment: @DaveHogan No, I get no result at all.

Comment: try data: {data} instead of data: {content:content}

Comment: Yet again, nothing. Want me to post some more code? Or anything I can do but saying nothing? :P

Comment: lol - how about - var data = "{content:"+content+"}";

Comment: If your still having problems - I'd suggest installing Fiddler and see if the HTTP request is even being made and in what data format.

Comment: You probably miss the `:` at `success function (data) {` try change it to `success:function (data) {`

Comment: @sofl Good spot! I completely missed that :)

Comment: Still doesn't give any errors/output/anything.

Comment: did you see in firebug  if it really execute the ajax script ? I mean is your click event really working ?

Comment: @Arfeen And How would I do that

Comment: $("a").click(function() { messing up someway..

Comment: "a" is that some id of button or DIV ? so if it is an ID of any container, button etc, then i think it should be $("#a"). If its a class then it should be $(".a")

Comment: @John : Please validate an answer

Comment: @John : Please validate an answer

Answer (score 0):

You miss " : " after success

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {

            var content = $('#content').html();

            var data = {"content":content};


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {content:content},
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Hello!');
                }

            });


        });

    });        
</script>

<div id="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As @sofl said, if you change it to `success:function (data) {` it will work!

Just remember that the `$("a")` from `$("a").click(function() {` called when click in a link tag like `<a href"">`.

If you are using an input ou button with a `class="a"` you should change the code to `$(".a").click(function() {`

(just add a `.` before `a`)

PS: If you're using a link, you should set the `href=""` to `href="#"` to work.